# Cancel previous promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, cancellation

I am implementing a search input in my React app which may take several seconds for a response from  the server based on the size of the result set. The issue I am having right now is if the user searches for a term which has a large result set and then searches for a term with a small result set straight after, the first search is returning after the last search and is overwriting the data, therefore displaying incorrect results on the table.

Currently I have a search component which calls an async function in its parent (this function can be called from several child components, Search being one of them). Inside the async function I have an await call to the service with the search query. Once that returns the results are passed to a function which updates some state.

I have read about cancel tokens but i'm not totally sure how to implement this. When the search component makes the initial call, there will be a promise which will be pending until the result is received. When I search again, how would I be able to ignore the result of the first promise? Each time I search, would I store the promise in a field of the component and somehow check this field in future searches?

I read many possible solutions to this online. I am using `fetch-retry` to handle the API call and would rather not use a library such as `bluebird` or `axios`. The main part I don't understand is how to have my promise not resolve if a promise has been created in future.

Hope I explained this well enough!

Thanks

Comment: ES6 promises aren't cancellable. End of the story. It's a thing that produces a promise that can be cancellable. Axios provides cancellation. As for Fetch, it's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort . If you're interested in getting an answer, consider providing specific information about your case. Please, don't try to describe the code, this never works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code-related questions.

Comment: A React-y way of doing, as advises by the official documentation, is to create an abortable promise : https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Answer (score 2):

> When I search again, how would I be able to ignore the result of the first promise?

You probably don't want that, as youbare wasting some bandwith if you do a request and ignore its result. Instead you should cancel the underlying request (not the promise, promises can't be canceled directly).

To do so you could keep an abortion controller for each search:

```
 this.controller = new AbortController();
```

Then launch all fetch requests as:

```
 fetch(url, { signal: this.controller.signal })
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => this.setState({ /*...*/ }))
   .catch(() => /*..*/)
```

Now if you restart the search just do:

```
 this.controller.abort();
 this.controller = new AbortController();
```

and do the fetching again.

[Read on](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch)

Comment: Here is the browser compatibility chart for this : https://caniuse.com/#search=abort

Comment: Thanks, I read about AbortController too but I don't think its usable on IE11 and the restricted environment i am in does not have the polyfill available to install. If I was to use AbortController, would I simply have a single instance in my main component state. When the search function is called, I pass that controller into the api function call and attach it to fetch. Then I call `this.controller.abort()` at the start of my search function?

Comment: @sam no, you should tie it to the components that manage it (`Search` ?)